# What is the current passing through wire AB as a function of angle theta?

Tags: electric-circuits

This is a high school contest(CAP) question:
[image]

Consider a circuit made of a wire with uniform resistance in a shape of a circle as shown in the picture. The circle is connected diagonally from point A to point B with the same type of wire. If the current passing through the circuit is *$\ i_0 $*, what is the current passing through the wire AB as a function of angle θ?

The answer is: 
$$\frac{\pi - 2\theta}{\pi + 4}  i_0 $$

Any help or hint will be appreciated!!! Thanks!

Comment: It can often help to consider the extreme cases first.  How would it be different if wire AB was horizontal in the diagram compared to if it were vertical?  Which set up do you think would offer the least resistance?  Another suggestion: redraw the diagram with resistor symbols instead of segments of wire keeping in mind that the longer the segments are the higher the resistance value will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: $\frac{\pi-2\theta}{\pi + 4}I_{0}$

Hint: 
The length of the arcs as well as the length of the segment AB should be taken as a measure of the resistance of the corresponding segments. Plus you need to know how does current breaks into two parts when encountering an intersection. The make use of *Kirchhoff's laws*. (both conservations of energy and charge)